Add a div class to all the fields in shipping form in magento2
I want to customize my shipping and billing form in magento one page checkout process and for that I have to add a custom CSS class/div class to shipping and billing form.If anyone have any leads, Please help
code of checkout_index_index.xml
 referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- Shipping step -->

                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkout.steps.shipping-step.step-config</item>
                                                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="popUpForm" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="element" xsi:type="string">#opc-new-shipping-address</item>
                                                            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="type" xsi:type="string">popup</item>
                                                                <item name="responsive" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                <item name="innerScroll" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Address</item>
                                                                <item name="trigger" xsi:type="string">opc-new-shipping-address</item>
                                                                <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Ship here</item>
                                                                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action primary action-save-address</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="cancel" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cancel</item>
                                                                        <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action secondary action-hide-popup</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                                    <item name="listingOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="customer-email" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">customer-email</item>
                                                            <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">We'll send your order confirmation here.</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="before-login-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-login-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- before login form fields -->
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="additional-login-form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-login-form-fields</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- additional login form fields -->
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- before form fields -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="before-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-fields</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- before fields -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="address-list" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-list</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="address-list-additional-addresses" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">address-list-additional-addresses</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- address-list-additional-addresses -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-shipping-method-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <!-- address-list-additional-addresses -->
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="deps" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">additional-fieldsets</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="firstname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="lastname" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="street" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="city" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">6</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="region_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">7</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>


@Tisha Jhanwar
Hey,
You can do this via LayoutProcessor Plugin for shipping and billing both. In this plugin create new component and template file for each fields. Also, you can add your custom block file in checkout_index_index.xml where you can add custom css as well.
Thank You!
